# What is the minimum code required to open a window?

Tags: x11, gui

I have been playing with C code recently and I am wondering how some features are implemented, specifically window creation.

I have used SDL for a bit, but it seems to rely on X11 (or Wayland). But X11 itself is written in C, so how does it create a window? Can I go even lower?

I am not aware of a syscall to do this, for example.

This is for educational purposes only, not for production.

Answer (score 0):

X11 is a client server architecture, where a client can request a window. The server is the thing that actually displays things, the client is the application program.

As a client software, you usually use libX11 to do these requests.

Nobody would develop a gui application directly based on X11 anymore, for good reason: a lot of the design of X11 does not reflect how you would want to write such an application anymore. For example, X11 has fundamental drawing routines for things like lines or boxes. But making a request through a protocol for every line you draw has very high overhead. So, instead a sensible client will simply draw these things on a surface(a bitmap if you will) and send the changed regions to the server on block.

Furthermore, especially when you're using SDL, you have to realize that this strict separation between client and server had been to be broken anyway, to enable things like OpenGL or just to avoid having to copy bitmaps though X11, and instead directly allow applications to write to GPU buffers.

Furthermore, I think it's fair to say that with practically all developers of X.org which were active in the past decade on feature development have done that in Wayland, that learning how to do low-level X11 in 2023 might not be the wisest choice. Wayland isn't quite there yet, but it's clear that X's days are numbered.

That's another good reason to not do low level X11 calls yourself anymore. You're excluding yourself from a growing number of platforms (or add another layer of indirection - the xwayland server emulating an X11 server within Wayland for single windows, which then work more or less - for example, XWayland simply can't do the native hidpi support).

So, to answer the question "how much code is it?": not much, unless you want to do it usefully. You want to initialize libX11 with thread support, you need to set up handlers, you need to initialize input handling, initialize at least xdamage, you need to set up the window, get a surface, and then start drawing on it. That all in a 1980's ductus of C. Honestly, there's better times to be had. Use a framework like SDL, GTK4, FLTK... I personally found that DearImgui ships with understandable examples based on different ways of speaking to your graphics system, and while these do abstract the gritty details of getting the X11 window, you do get a good feeling because you can look inside how a GUI interacts, when it's built on modern GPU Interfaces instead of a desktop idea from when 4 MB were unreasonably much RAM.

Comment: Thank you for the insights, I will take a look at DearImgui